# How to detect custom marker orientation using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

For my project, i need to estimate 6d pose and identify custom markers.

The marker will be a letter with a red/green background and a white border like below[image: Marker]

Using standard image processing like canny edge detection,contour detection, I was able to easily detect the four corner of the markers in image space and using camera matrix and physical marker dimension(20cm*20cm) and `cv2 solvepnpransac` i was able to detect the xyz position of the marker with respect to the camera.But if the marker was not upright or tilted,thex -y axises shifted and the orientaion estimate was just plain wrong. In other words as there is no way to detect to detect upright postion of the marker with just 4 points.

**How can i detect which image point of the marker, corresponds to which world point of the marker?**

Comment: One silly way is to use Template Matching to find the approximate rotation of the marker. Simply rotate a template image by N degrees and try to match this template  with the Marker that was detected. When you get a high degree of similarity (90%) between them you'll know that the Marker is rotated N degrees.